# Rails & Papertrail - Include previous version in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, arel, paper-trail-gem

I'm creating an application the requires Admin approval when articles are created and updated.  I used paper trail to accomplish this, storing each update to the articles.

When an article is updated, the "published" field is set to false.  Since I want to display the most recent Approved/Published version of the article, I need a sort of scope that checks if the current version of the article is approved, and if it is not, it searches back through previous versions until it finds an approved/published one.

```
def self.published(query={})
  where(query).map do |article|
    article.published? ? article : article.last_published_version
  end.compact! || []
end

def published?()
  published
end

def last_published_version()
  return self if published?
  published_versions = versions.select{ |version| version.reify.try(:published?) } 
  published_versions.present? ? published_versions.last.reify : nil
end
```

Now, since I am using `map` here, my query is returning an array instead of a ActiveRecord Relation.  I would like to chain additional queries on the published articles, so this is a problem.

For example, I would like to do:
`Article.published.where(...).order_by(...)`, etc

Any ideas on accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making a direct association and `joins` the 2 together so you can add search terms against the versioning table. I would also use a custom version class (not that you can't do this with the default version table) and set the meta data you would regularly access (or need to access for the search), as the version is serialized, through their `meta` option. Would probably be faster and searching/accessing data would be more convenient this way.

Comment: Thanks, your input was very helpful.  I've come up with queries that allow me to to get all of the relevant rows from the tables (if it's set to published in the articles table, I grab that row, otherwise I grab the row from the versions table).  However, what I end up with is a combination of usable rows, and rows that have serialized data.  Adding metadata would solve the problem, but I need basically all of the fields, and I don't think it's a good idea to recreate all of those columns in the versions table.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you explain "usable rows" and "rows that have serialized data", what is the difference?

Comment: I think he means that he gets a mix of Articles and Versions where Articles are "usable" (regular objects), but Versions contain serialised data. Ideally you'll always get the same type of objects back. – @RyanB I realise this question is 3 years old, but I'm running into the same problem and would love to hear what you ultimately ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `has_many :versions, as: :item, class_name: 'PaperTrail::Version'` to your model, then you can use `include(:versions)`. However, this won't eager query for all PaperTrail queries such as `version_at` because that query includes a created_at scope. What you can do instead of using the `version_at` method is something like `Foo.includes(:versions).first.versions.find { |f| f.created_at > date }`. This is suggested in PaperTrail's issues [here](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/issues/222).

Me wanting to `include(:versions)` for multiple `Foo`, I did a separate query for versions after querying for Foo

```
    foo_versions = PaperTrail::Version.where(
      item_type: 'Publication',
      item_id: foos.map(&:id),
    ).where("created_at >= ?", date).order(:created_at)
```

and then I built a lookup index

```
    foo_index = foo_versions.each_with_object({}) do |foo, mapping|
      mapping[foo.item_id] ||= foo
    end
```

This allowed me to omit a n+1 query situation.